# Is there a CLI command to report if vagrant provisioning is complete?

Tags: vagrant

While `vagrant up` is executing, any call to `vagrant status` will report that the machine is 'running', even if the provisioning is not yet complete.

Is there a simple command for asking whether the `vagrant up` call is done and the machine is fully-provisioned?

Comment: There's nothing really, you could also run a shell command like 'ping www.google.com` and provisioning will never be complete, it will just hang as command will never complete. you can check if vagrant process is still running but there's nothing like vagrant option to know about provisioning status

Answer (score 0):

You could have your provision script write to a networked file and query that. Or you could `vagrant ssh -c /check/for/something` if there was a file or service to check agains. Your provision script could also ping out to a listener you set up.

You could also use the Vagrant log or debug output to check when provisioning is done.